# Google Analytics: How do I create a custom report to view today's top visited pages by page title?

Tags: google, google-analytics

I'm trying set a "Custom Report" that shows today's top visited pages by page title.

Here's a picture of what I have set so far:

[image]

I tried to filter by "Date" with "Today" selected, but that does not seem to work.

Does anyone know how to set a Custom Report to automatically filter for "Today" only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. Based on where you left off in the picture you added:

1. Remove the `Filters`
2. Click `Save` and give it a name
3. Click `Add to Dashboard`
4. Select your Dashboard from the pull down list (e.g., My Dashboard) and click `Add to Dashboard`
5. Select the table from the list you just named
6. Click on the `Day` tab

Now you should see all the top page views for that title by today's date.

To view this again later, just go to `Dashboards` on the left navigation strip and click on the name of your Dashboard (e.g., My Dashboard). To view by another day/date range, just select the day or date range in the upper right corner.

Comment: You're welcome :-) Now you know which pages are the best, and can start to drive visitors to other pages from those, and retain them longer... Good luck!